# I've tried various ways to get the value of my jquery spinner but its just not happening

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm back with more questions.

First off I want to thank everyone who has helped me out along the way with my questions on jQuery sliders and spinners. But now I have run into an issue and have tried various ways to get the value of my spinner.

my spinner is...

```
function updateTopBottom() {
    var $el = $('#topbottom'),
        m;
    var myData = $("#topbottom input").val();
    $("#Label3").text(myData);
}


$(function () {


    $('#normal input').spinner();


    $('#topbottom input').spinner({
        min: 0,
        max: 12,
        step: 0.5,
        stop: updateTopBottom
    })
            .parent()
            .find('.ui-spinner-up').addClass('ui-corner-tl').end()
            .find('.ui-spinner-down').addClass('ui-corner-bl');

    updateTopBottom();
});
```

As you can see I have set a variable in a function to get the spinner value. Then I try to set a label with the variable. This isn't working.

my markup for this particular part is this..

```
<td><div class="c-input" id="topbottom">
    <div class="c-field c-topbottom">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input value="0" style="width: 29px"/> </div>
```

I understand that my spinner is an input type, with that I have tried using adding an onclick to the input so I can have my label change to the value of the spinner. But that hasn't worked out to well for me.

So, as usual I'm kinda stuck with this. I've tagged this question with asp and c# as well because I am doing this with asp.net and maybe someone with asp.net or c# may have come across this issue and provide input as well on how the accomplished it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

Why are you writing a spinner? I don't mean to be a troll but I suggest you use libraries to your advantage. This is a great spinner with plenty of options and configuration.

Comment: That wasn't the spinner I was speaking of, the one I'm speaking of is one that you click and the numbers go up and down